# Automatic Reference Counting: Pointer to non-const type 'NSError *' with no explicit ownership

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

In updating some of my code to be in compatible with the iOS 5 SDK, I attempted to refactor my code by using "Convert to Objective-C ARC" in Xcode and received an error.  The error occurs on an instance variable in my .h file.

```
NSError **_error;
```

The error says "Pointer to non-const type 'NSError *' with no explicit ownership."  How might I fix this?

Comment: This question (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907726/setting-nserror-within-a-block-using-arc) is the closest thing I can find on the subject.

Comment: Why are you using double indirection in an instance variable?  You should only need that for method parameters so that NSErrors can be passed back up.

Comment: @BradLarson ok, so what's the correct way (in ARC) to initialize an `NSError` instance when calling a method that takes `(NSError**):error` as an argument?

Comment: @SAFX - Same as you did before ARC, `NSError *error = nil;` and then you'll just pass `&error` into your method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When storing `NSError` objects in an instance variable you have to declare it as a simple pointer:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    NSError *_errror;
}
```

`NSError **` is only used to indirectly return `NSError` objects from a method to the caller. It is (probably) an error to store it in an instance variable.

Answer (score 60):

You can use one of the lifetime qualifiers described in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)

For NSError ** you'd use __autoreleasing so the example provided by Nikolai would then look like this

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    NSError * __autoreleasing *error;
}
```

The syntax is a little weird and you should follow Nikolais advice, but if you're sure NSError ** is what you want this should work.

Comment: This doesn't compile, try `NSError * __autoreleasing *_error;`

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is not wrong to do this as the answer by @NikolaiRuhe states.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I'd like to add that I've also used other lifetime qualifiers with this same syntax, like `NSArray * __strong *array`, etc.