# 2D Array Of Pointers in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am programming an iPhone game which has items laid out on a grid. Each item is represented by an object, and I want to use a 2D array to represent the contents of the grid. Since I will need to be passing the array through methods, I have attempted to declare it as:

```
MyClass*** grid;
```

and have a method to return it as:

```
-(MyClass ***) {
    return grid
}
```

But before even compiling i get this error:

```
Pointer to non-const type 'MyClass *' with no explicit ownership.
```

What does this mean, and why would it happen?

Comment: Are you using automatic reference counting?

Comment: ARC requires explicit ownership. Pointers to object pointers have unknown owners, so it won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7804435/ which is similar.

Comment: The suggested answer on that question is to store the NSError** as a simple pointer. However, that is not an option here (I believe). Could you suggest another alternative?

Comment: You could use manual reference counting, or you can use nested `NSArray`s. If the number of elements in your C-array is known at compile time, you can declare the array as `MyClass *grid[20][20]` and it should work.

Comment: But I need to pass it. I was under the impression that passing arrays was forbidden, and to do so you were required to pass a pointer instead.

Comment: Then you should either use manual reference counting or nested `NSArray`s.

Comment: Damn. Thanks for the info, if you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Automatic Reference Counting you cannot have pointers to object pointers that way, since the owner will be unknown.

You can use nested `NSArray` objects instead, or switch to manual reference counting (you shouldn't do the latter if you already have a large project).

---

You could also instead have a method like this which the callee will call multiple times (once for each cell in the grid):

```
- (id)itemAtX:(NSUInteger)x y:(NSUInteger)y {
  // TODO: Add bounds checking.
  return grid[x][y];
}
```

Comment: I dont' know about using an NSArray, since I'm attempting to represent a grid of data with it, and NSArrays are dynamically sized. I suppose I could set the objects that I wanted to be filled to `nil`.

Comment: I'd recommend using NSNull object instead

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the standard C 2D array for this,

```
MyClass *item = (MyClass *)grid[x][y];
```

Comment: How would I then go about passing/returning `grid` from a method?

Comment: Remember that objective C is a superset of C, so you can pass C around as you wish. Take a look at http://borkwarellc.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/its-still-just-c-arrays-and-pointers/

Comment: So, in answer to your question: - (MyClass *)returnGrid:(MyClass *) grid { // do something to the grid... return grid }